Set of "efficient" points in different metrics
Given metric $d$ and a set of $k$ points $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called efficient if there is no other point that is closer to all of the $x_i$. Formally, a point $y$ is efficient if there is no other point $z$ such that $d(z,x_i) <  d(y,x_i)$ for all $i$ in $1,\ldots,k$.
Question 1: If $d$ is the Euclidean metric, what is the set of efficient points? My guess is that it is simply the convex hull of $x_1,\ldots,x_k$, since for every point $y$ outside this convex hull, there is a plane that separates it from the convex hull, and if we move $y$ towards the plane, then it becomes closer to all the $x_i$. But I could not find a formal proof.
Question 2: If $d$ is the taxicab ($\ell_1$) metric, what is the set of efficient points? If my first guess is correct, then I would guess that this would be some adaptation of the "convex hull" to  $\ell_1$ metric, but I have no idea how such adaptation would look like.

NOTE: the term "efficiency" comes from term Pareto efficiency in economics. The points $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ represent households; the point $y$ represents the location of some useful facility, e.g. a school. The location is Pareto efficient if no other location is better (nearer) for all the households. 

Q1: The set of efficient points for the Euclidean metric is precisely the convex hull.
Let $x = \sum_i \lambda_i x_i$ for $\lambda_i\ge0$ and $\sum_i \lambda_i=1$.
Suppose there is another point $\hat x$ such that $\|\hat x - x_i \|_2^2 \le \|x-x_i\|_2^2$ for all $i$.
Then
$$
0 \ge \frac12 \|\hat x - x_i \|_2^2 -\frac12 \|x-x_i\|_2^2
= \langle x-x_i, \hat x - x \rangle + \frac12 \| \hat x - x\|_2^2.
$$
Multiplying the inequality with $\lambda_i$ and taking sum over $i$ yields
$$
0 \ge \sum_i \lambda_i ( \langle x-x_i, \hat x - x \rangle + \frac12 \| \hat x - x\|_2^2)
=\langle x-\sum_i \lambda_i x_i, \hat x - x \rangle + \frac12 \| \hat x - x\|_2^2
= \frac12 \| \hat x - x\|_2^2,
$$
so that $\hat x = x $ follows. Hence every point in the convex hull is efficient.
Now suppose that $x$ does not belong to $conv(x_1 \dots x_k)$. Let $P$ denote the projection onto $conv(x_1 \dots x_k)$. Then
$$
\frac12 \|x - x_i\|_2^2 -\frac12 \| Px - x_i \|_2^2 = 
\langle Px-x_i, x-Px\rangle + \frac12 \|Px-x\|_2^2 > \langle  Px-x,x_i-Px\rangle \ge 0,
$$
and $x$ cannot be efficient.
The above remains correct, if you replace the finitely many points $x_1 \dots x_k$ by an arbitrary set $M$, and the convex hull by the closed convex hull of $M$.
Q2: for the $l_1$ metric the situation seems to be completely different. For example, if $x_1 = (0,0)$ and $x_2=(1,1)$ then all points in $[0,1]^2$ are efficient. Because all these points satisfy
$$
\|x-x_1\|_1 + \|x-x_2\|_1 = 2 = \|x_1-x_2\|_1.
$$

For a metric $d$, define a set as "convex" if, for any two points in the set, all shortest paths between the points are also in the set. When $d$ is the Euclidean metric, there is only one shortest path, and we get the standard definition of a convex set. For the $l_1$ metric, there may be many shortest paths. In particular, the "convex hull" of $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ in the $l_1$ metric is indeed the unit square. So maybe the convex hull lemma is still true for this definition?
